# c# initialization of a structure with lambda as a member

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lambda

Is it possible to initialize a structure with lambda as a member?

I tried:

```
struct lambdas
{
    Func<bool> func1;
}

lambdas l = { () => true };
```

But it I get an error:

> error CS1660 "Can not convert lambda expression to type 'object'
>   because it is not a delegate type".

Comment: Pretty obvious. Your `struct` **contains** a `Func` as memmber. However it **is** none itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntactically (assuming `func1` is actually accessible):

```cs
var l = new lambdas { func1 = () => true };
```

Not sure I'd do this myself, though... mutable structs are a bad idea, usually. As a `readonly struct`, perhaps it would be fine:

```cs
readonly struct SomeBetterName
{
    public Func<bool> SomeFunc {get;}
    public SomeBetterName(Func<bool> someFunc)
        => SomeFunc = someFunc;
}
```

with:

```cs
var l = new SomeBetterName(() => true);
```

but fundamentally, if your struct only contains a delegate, one wonders why not just pass the delegate directly.

Comment: Thanks. The structure contains a lot of fields. I actually need to have an array of structures and I would like to initialize it in a simple way (like in C++): {{field1, field2,…},{field1, field2, …}…}. As far as I understand – it is impossible in C#. I would highlight it in your answer